# Detecting the rising edge of an std_logic signal in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have a flip flop which uses as clk input a signal which comes from the processing of to other signals. That means, that I'm not using the clock of the system neither an input. Thus, when I do:

```
architecture sampler_a of sampler_e is
  signal S0_s   : std_logic := '0';  
begin
  -- In my block this is not only a not. I put this to simplify things.
  S0_s <= not(S0_i);                   
  S0_o <= S0_s;

  process(S0_i)
  begin
    --Also with rising edge does not work
    if (S0_s'event and S0_s= '1') then
        BitReady_o <= '1';
    end if;   
  end process;
end sampler_a;
```

BitReady does not change in the simulation (in modelsim). Is the use of std_logic incorrect here?
Note that I don't want to generate a pulse that is a clock period's wide, because my circuit works in an asynchronous way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is only sensitive to `S0_i`, but only tests for events on `S0_s` (which are never in the same delta cycle as `S0_i` events). Thus the process can never do anything.

Change its sensitivity list to `S0_s` and if ought to work.
However, as currently written, once `BitReady_o` becomes `'1'`, there is no way to ever return it to `'0'`.

Comment: Perfect! It worked! The thing about the BitReady that never goes to '0' is only because I simplified the code a lot. I didn't realized that signals could also be added to the sensitivity list. I thought only inputs. One more thing I learned! Thanks a lot.

Comment: VHDL has fewer restrictions than people often expect : if the grammar permits it and the compiler doesn't complain about it, it probably works. In this case, once you are inside an architecture, a port signal appears the same as any other signal (qualified by its mode : don't write to an "in" port!)